# Can XPath match on parts of an element's name?

Tags: xml, xpath

I want to do this:

> //*fu

which returns all nodes whose name ends in **fu**, such as `<tarfu />` and `<snafu />`, but not `<fubar />`

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Do something like:

```
//*[ends-with(name(), 'fu')]
```

For a good XPath reference, check out [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xsl_functions.asp).

Comment: This is an XPath 2.0 solution only.

Comment: note that you can use `local-name()` to omit namespaces in complex XML

Answer (score 52):

**This answer is for [XPath 1.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath#section-String-Functions)** where there is no equivalent of the [XPath 2.0 standard ends-with() function](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-ends-with).

The following XPath 1.0 expression selects all elements in the xml document, whose names end with the string "fu":

```
//*[substring(name(),string-length(name())-1) = 'fu']
```

**Note** that ***`-1` is the offset from the end of `name()` (the length of `"fu"` minus one***), so that the string comparison performed within **`substring()`** starts at the right position from the end of the string.

Similarly, if it was needed to determine whether **`"asdf"`** was a suffix of the name, then  **`string-length(name())-3`** must be specified.

Comment: Thanks for this helpful comment. I was trying to do this with lxml, which supports ends-with, but not on element names. Your answer was exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 2):

I struggled with Dimitre Novatchev's answer, it wouldn't return matches. I knew your XPath must have a section telling that "fu" has length 2.

It's advised to have a string-length('fu') to determine what to substring.

For those who aren't able to get results with his answer and they require solution with xpath 1.0:

`//*[substring(name(), string-length(name()) - string-length('fu') +1) = 'fu']`

> Finds matches of elements ending with "fu"

or

`//*[substring(name(), string-length(name()) - string-length('Position') +1) = 'Position']`

> Finds matches to elements ending with "Position"