# How to get node value using variable node name?

Tags: xpath, xquery

I have an XML document like:

```
<data>
    <item type="apple">
        <misc>something</misc>
        <appleValue>23</appleValue>
        <misc2>something else</misc2>
    </item>
    <item type="banana">
        <bananaValue>47</bananaValue>
        <random>something</random>
    </item>
</data>
```

I can get the items with `doc("data.xml")/data/item` but I need to get the text from the elements that end with `Value`. So I'd like to get "23" and "47", but I don't necessarily know the element names, meaning all I really know is there are elements that end in `Value`, I don't know if it's `appleValue`, `bananaValue`, etc. except that I could look at the `type` attribute and buildup a string.

```
let $type := (doc("data.xml")/data/item)[1]/@type
doc("data.xml")/data/item/$typeValue
```

...That last line is what I'm trying to get at, clearly that's not correct but I need to find elements whose name is known based on a variable (stored in a variable such as `$type`) and "Value".

Any ideas? I realize this variable element naming is strange/odd/bad...but that's the way it is and I have to deal with it.

Answer (score 3):

I got it thanks to this post: [Can XPath match on parts of an element's name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46125/can-xpath-match-on-parts-of-an-elements-name)

```
doc("data.xml")/data/item/*[ends-with(name(), "Value")]
```

Answer (score 3):

I would avoid using the `name()` function in favor of either `node-name()` or `local-name()`. The reason for this is that `name()` can give you different answers depending on what (and whether) namespace prefixes are used in the source. For example, the following three elements have the same exact name (QName):

```
<appleValue xmlns="http://example.com"/>
<x:appleValue xmlns:x="http://example.com"/>
<y:appleValue xmlns:y="http://example.com"/>
```

However, the `name()` function will give you a different answer for each one (`appleValue`, `x:appleValue`, and `y:appleValue`, respectively). So you're better off either ignoring the namespace by using `local-name()` (which returns the string `appleValue` for all three of the above cases) or explicitly specifying the namespace (even if it's empty, as Oliver showed), using `node-name()` (which returns a proper QName value, rather than a string). In this case, since you're not using namespaces (and since even if you added one later, the code will still work), I'd be slightly in favor of using `local-name()` as follows:

```
doc("data.xml")/data/item/*['Value' eq substring-after(local-name(),../@type)]
```

For elaboration on reasons to avoid the `name()` function (and exceptions), see ["Perils of the name function"](http://lenzconsulting.com/namespaces-in-xslt/#perils_of_the_name_function).

Answer (score 1):

You can access the name of the node using `name()`.  XPath 1.0 does not have an "ends-with" function, but by using `substring()` and `string-length()` - 1 you can get there.

```
//item/*[ substring(  name(),  string-length(name() ) - 4  ) = 'Value']
```

Answer (score 0):

A more precise way to implement this would be

```
for $item in doc("data.xml")/data/item
let $value-name := fn:QName('', concat($item/@type, 'Value'))
return $item/*[node-name() = $value-name]
```